# HTTP POST mutli part "BAD REQUEST"

Tags: c, http-headers, http-post, winsock

I'm trying to upload a file using POST

here's my request :

```
POST /upload.php HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------552335022525
Content-Length: 192
-----------------------------552335022525
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="userfile"; filename="12.txt"
Content-Type: text/plain


blabla
-----------------------------552335022525--
```

Using HTTP live headers firefox plugin everything works

but when putting it a char *buffer and send it with  winsocksapi I get 400 Bad Request error

Comment: How are you putting it in the `char*` buffer?

Comment: char *sendBuffer="the whole thing";

Comment: when using `send()`, are you paying attention to the return value? `send()` can send fewer bytes then requested, so you have to loop it. Also, are you paying attention ot return codes, especially WSAEWOULDBLOCK if you are using a on-blocking socket? Please show your actual sending code.  BTW, you are missing a needed CRLF between the `Content-Length` header and the first boundary line. The HTTP headers are terminated by 2 CRLFs.

Comment: @bit8bug, but you can't have newlines in character constants. That is what I want to see. Also, can you add a tag for the language you're using?

Comment: @RemyLebeau, @DarkFalcon Thanks guys , the problem was in Content-Length 2 CRLFs . does this loop looks okay 

` while ( (iResult = send(clientSock, sendBuffer, (int)strlen(sendBuffer), 0)) < (int)strlen(sendBuffer), 0);`
@DarkFalcon
can you post the comment as answer so I can mark it answered

Comment: @DarkFalcon: you can have line breaks in string constants, using `\r` and `\n`.

Comment: @bit8bug: no, your loop is not ok, not even close. Each time `send()` returns a value >0, increment `sendBuffer` by that many characters and continue looping, until there are no more characters left. If `send()` returns -1, call `WSAGetLastError()`. If it returns any value other than `WSAEWOULDBLOCK`, it is an error so stop looping.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, Sure! But those are escape sequences for line breaks, not line breaks. I was expecting to see that he used only '\n' to escape, or something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a blank line between the headers and the payload.

```
Content-Length: 192

-----------------------------552335022525
```

This is part of the HTTP protocol. HTTP request headers end with the first empty line (CR-LF by itself.) What you are sending is resulting in the string

```
-----------------------------552335022525
```

being taken (along with the following two lines) as a request header which, of course, it isn't.  The server can't make head or tail of that, so it responds with 400 Bad Request.

Also, sending the Content-length is not necessary with multipart/form-data, nor even a good idea, as the wrong value could create problems. The MIME multipart format is self describing.